# A way to remove treeview border

Tags: python, tkinter

Like the title, I want to remove the border of the treeview tkinter

```
# I have two columns that span 2 of the lower columns, ColumnA and ColumnB
self.tree_heading = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=("ColumnA", "ColumnB"), show="headings", height=0)
self.tree_heading.column("ColumnA", width=200)
self.tree_heading.column("ColumnB", width=200)
        
self.tree_heading.heading("ColumnA", text="Column A")
self.tree_heading.heading("ColumnB", text="Column B")
self.tree_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 0))

# Here are the four lower columns
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=("Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"), show="headings")

self.tree.column("Column1", anchor="center", width=100)
self.tree.column("Column2", anchor="center", width=100)
self.tree.column("Column3", anchor="center", width=100)
self.tree.column("Column4", anchor="center", width=100)

self.tree.heading("Column1", text="Column 1", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading("Column2", text="Column 2", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading("Column3", text="Column 3", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading("Column4", text="Column 4", anchor="center")
```

Basically, here I want the top treeview to not have a border but I cannot find a way to resolve this.

```
self.style = ttk.Style()
self.style.configure("Custom.Treeview", borderwidth=0, relief="flat")
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work

I wanted to make a a table using the tkinter treeview and I needed a way to create two row headers where the top row header would span the two columns below. I have succeeded but the top treeview has a bottom border which I wanted to remove. Using treeview might not be the answer but I want to know if there might be a way for this to be possible using it

Comment: all may depends on system. Maybe on some systems it can't remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure but in `style` you may need to use `'Treeview'` instead of `Custom.Treeview`. Or you may need to assign style to treeview - `ttk.Treeview(..., style="Custom.Treeview")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help?  `self.style = ttk.Style()` and then `self.style.theme_use("default")`

Comment: this is the exact problem: [link](https://imgur.com/a/YcGdYdA)

Answer (score 0):

A fairly straightforward way i can think of is to define a custom layout for your desired treeview widget, `Edge.Treeview` for instance;

```
...
    self.style = ttk.Style()
    ...
    # Make sure that the treearea element is in the house!
    self.style.layout(
        'Edge.Treeview',
        [('Edge.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nsew'})],
    )
    # Another handy tweak!
    self.style.configure('Edge.Treeview', highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
```

Now that we have a custom layout, let's reference it!

```
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, ..., style='Edge.Treeview')
```